# XSLT For Breaking Elements Into Sets?

Tags: xml, xslt, batch-file

Is XSLT a good solution for breaking an XML document into sets by element name? For example, if my document is:

```
<mydocument>
<items>
<item>one</item>
<item>two</item>
<item>three</item>
<item>four</item>
</items>
</mydocument>
```

I want to split this into sets of 3 or less like:

```
<mydocument>
<items page="1">
<item>one</item>
<item>two</item>
<item>three</item>
</items>
<items page="2">
<item>four</item>
</items>
</mydocument>
```

Can someone provide me with a XSLT approach, or even better, an example.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSetSize" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <mydocument>
   <xsl:for-each select=
     "item[position() mod $vSetSize = 1]">
     <items page="{position()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select=
       ". | following-sibling::*
               [not(position() >= $vSetSize)]"/>
     </items>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </mydocument>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted result**:

```
<mydocument>
    <items page="1">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
        <item>three</item>
    </items>
    <items page="2">
        <item>four</item>
    </items>
</mydocument>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using `not(position() >= $vSetSize)` instead of `position() < $vSetSize`?

Comment: @David: No reason, except for readability -- I try to avoid having to escape "<".

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that.  Forgive the n00b question :)